# Fill missing values based on spatial clustering method in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, k-means, dbscan

Given a dataframe as follows:

```
     latitude   longitude         user_service
0  -27.496404  153.014353      02: Duhig Tower
1  -27.497107  153.014836                  NaN
2  -27.497118  153.014890                  NaN
3  -27.497154  153.014813                  NaN
4  -27.496437  153.014477      12: Duhig North
5  -27.497156  153.014813  32: Gordon Greenwod
6  -27.497097  153.014746       23: Abel Smith
7  -27.496390  153.014415  32: Gordon Greenwod
8  -27.497112  153.014780           03: Steele
9  -27.497156  153.014813  32: Gordon Greenwod
10 -27.496487  153.014622      02: Duhig Tower
11 -27.497075  153.014532                  NaN
12 -27.497103  153.014817        25: UQ Sports
13 -27.496754  153.014504      02: Duhig Tower
14 -27.496567  153.014294      02: Duhig Tower
15 -27.497156  153.014813  32: Gordon Greenwod
```

Since `user_service` column has missing values, so I think maybe I could use spatial clustering method to fill nans.

For example, for the `latitude` and `longitude` pair `-27.497107, 153.014836` in the second row, if `02: Duhig Tower`'s location is most closest one to it by distance, so I would like to fill nan in `user_service` with `02: Duhig Tower` for this row. Same logic for the other missing rows.

How could I implement the logic above in Python? Thanks.

The output from Guillermo Mosse's solution, but there are still some `NaN`s:

```
     latitude   longitude                   user_service
0  -27.499012  153.015180               51: Zelman Cowen
1  -27.497600  153.014479                     03: Steele
2  -27.500054  153.013435         50: Hawken Engineering
3  -27.495979  153.009834                            NaN
4  -27.496748  153.017507            32: Gordon Greenwod
5  -27.495695  153.016178  38: UQ Multi Faith Chaplaincy
6  -27.497015  153.012492               01: Forgan Smith
7  -27.498797  153.017267                            NaN
8  -27.500508  153.011360                       75: AIBN
9  -27.496763  153.013795               01: Forgan Smith
10 -27.494909  153.017187                            NaN
11 -27.496384  153.013810                12: Duhig North
```

Check `NaN`s:

```
var = df.loc[[2]].user_service
print(var)
print(type(var))
print(len(var))
```

Out:

```
2    NaN
Name: user_service, dtype: object
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you would want to use Pandas' [interpolate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) with a custom distance function to fill NaN values, but the method doesn't seem to be extendable in any way.

A possible solution is to, for each datapoint, get the service_name of the closest data point that actually has a service_name. Here's a full working example of a possible solution:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame    ([
  [-27.496404,  153.014353,      "02: Duhig Tower"],
  [-27.497107,  153.014836,                  None],
  [-27.497118,  153.014890,                  None],
  [-27.497154,  153.014813,                  None],
  [-27.496437,  153.014477,      "12: Duhig North"],
  [-27.497156,  153.014813,  "32: Gordon Greenwod"],
  [-27.497097,  153.014746,       "23: Abel Smith"],
  [-27.496390,  153.014415,  "32: Gordon Greenwod"],
  [-27.497112,  153.014780,           "03: Steele"],
  [-27.497156,  153.014813,  "32: Gordon Greenwod"],
  [-27.496487,  153.014622,      "02: Duhig Tower"],
  [-27.497075,  153.014532,                  None],
  [-27.497103,  153.014817,        "25: UQ Sports"],
  [-27.496754,  153.014504,      "02: Duhig Tower"],
  [-27.496567,  153.014294,      "02: Duhig Tower"],
  [-27.497156,  153.014813,  "32: Gordon Greenwod"]],
    columns = ["latitude", "longitude", "user_service"])


def closest_point_service_name(point, points, user_services):
    """ Find closest point with non null user_service """

    #First we filter the points and user_services by the ones that don't have null user_service
    points = points[user_services != None]
    user_services = user_services[user_services != None]

    #we use cdist to get all distances between pairs of points
    distances = cdist([point], points)[0]

    #we don't want to consider the current point
    distances[distances == 0] = np.inf

    #we get the index of the closest point
    closest_point_index = distances.argmin()

    #we return the user_service of the closest point that has a user_service
    closest_point_user_service = user_services[closest_point_index]
    return closest_point_user_service

#we convert the lat and long to a pair
df['point'] = [(x, y) for x,y in zip(df['latitude'], df['longitude'])]

#we create the additional column
df['closest'] = [closest_point_service_name(x, np.asarray(list(df['point'])), np.asarray(list(df['user_service']))) for x in df['point']]

#finally, we fill nulls
df.user_service = df.user_service.fillna(df['closest'])

del df['closest']

df
```

This is the output:

```
latitude    longitude   user_service    point
0   -27.496404  153.014353  02: Duhig Tower     (-27.496404, 153.014353)
1   -27.497107  153.014836  25: UQ Sports   (-27.497107, 153.014836)
2   -27.497118  153.014890  25: UQ Sports   (-27.497118, 153.01489)
3   -27.497154  153.014813  32: Gordon Greenwod     (-27.497154, 153.014813)
4   -27.496437  153.014477  12: Duhig North     (-27.496437, 153.014477)
5   -27.497156  153.014813  32: Gordon Greenwod     (-27.497156, 153.014813)
6   -27.497097  153.014746  23: Abel Smith  (-27.497097, 153.014746)
7   -27.496390  153.014415  32: Gordon Greenwod     (-27.49639, 153.014415)
8   -27.497112  153.014780  03: Steele  (-27.497112, 153.01478)
9   -27.497156  153.014813  32: Gordon Greenwod     (-27.497156, 153.014813)
10  -27.496487  153.014622  02: Duhig Tower     (-27.496487, 153.014622)
11  -27.497075  153.014532  23: Abel Smith  (-27.497075, 153.014532)
12  -27.497103  153.014817  25: UQ Sports   (-27.497103, 153.014817)
13  -27.496754  153.014504  02: Duhig Tower     (-27.496754, 153.014504)
14  -27.496567  153.014294  02: Duhig Tower     (-27.496567, 153.014294)
15  -27.497156  153.014813  32: Gordon Greenwod     (-27.497156, 153.014813)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I tried with full data, some missing values are filled just by `nan`s. Any ideas?

Comment: See this line?     user_services = user_services[user_services != None]
Here I use this because I only want to consider non-null user services. In my example, null values are "None". You are probably using a different data type for your nulls. You can try using math.isnan() function.

Comment: So, in other words, my advice for you is to first understand which data type you are using for nan values and then update the corresponding line accordingly. Tell me if you didn't succeed!

Comment: You mean use `user_services = user_services[math.isnan(user_services)]` instead of `user_services = user_services[user_services != None]`

Comment: I would first just grab a row and check that math.isnan actually returns True on one of your null values, but yeah! Although, the other way around: you have to actually negate the isnan because you only want to keep non-nan values.

Comment: I also tried with `user_services = user_services[pd.notnull(user_services)]`, but I still get result with `nan`s.

Comment: My question is, is there any way for you to debug what you are doing? Print the content of user_services[pd.notnull(user_services)]. Do you see nans as well?

Comment: Yes, there are nans inside, example: `'94: Biological Sciences Lib' '01: Forgan Smith' '39: Colin Clark' 'nan' 'nan' 'nan' '78: General Purpose South' '50: Hawken Engineering' '61: JD Story' '67: Priestley' '12: Duhig North'`

Comment: Maybe the nans are strings? filter out also user_services[user_services != 'nan']

Comment: If that doesn't work, select a row of the dataframe via the index. For example, if the first row has a nan, let var = df[0].user_service, and then print type(var), len(var)...try EXPLORING what ARE those nan values. That's what jupyter notebooks are for.